# how can i use tabs between variables in python to create a single row with 3 columns?

Tags: python, tabs

This is basically my variables that I want to print:

`print n, bu, qui`

right now i have it like this:

`print n"\t", int(bu.total_seconds() * 1000)"\t", int(qui.total_seconds() * 1000)"\t"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `str.format`:

```
print "{}\t{}\t{}".format(n, int(bu.total_seconds() * 1000),int(qui.total_seconds() * 1000))
```

You can align your format many different ways use [str.format's Format Specification Mini-Language](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#formatspec)

Comment: No worries, you can right-align, left-align and a multitude of other things using str.format